# Performance improvement is needed in the code for divisor count(python)

Tags: python

```
def f(n):
    count, k = 0, 1
    while k*k < n:
        if n%k == 0:
            count += 2
            k += 1

    return count
```

It's a very simple code to get the number of divisor.
But it takes too long to perform, so I need to fix something, so where should I fix it?

It's a simple code, but strangely, it took too long to perform, so I didn't get the result

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Why are you adding 2 to count? The two answers given so far each produce different results so it might be worthwhile explaining exactly what this function is meant to achieve. Is it meant to count the number of prime factors? In order to clarify your problem provide some sample input values with their corresponding expected outputs

Answer (score -1):

In order to make this function efficient, is to reduce the number of iterations in the **while loop**. Currently, the loop iterates until k*k < n. However, we only need to iterate up to the integer value of the square root of n, because after that point, the factors start repeating.

Therefore, you can modify the while loop condition to while k <= int(n**0.5): which will iterate only up to the integer value of the square root of n. Also, you need to handle the case where n is a perfect square separately, by incrementing the count by 1 at the end of the loop.

In your current code, you are incrementing k in an if condition which will not always meet and will make the program stuck in an infinite loop if, the condition is never met.

Here is a modified version of your code!

```
def f(n):
    count, k = 0, 1
    while k <= int(n**0.5):
        if n%k == 0:
            count += 2
        k += 1
    if int(n**0.5)**2 == n:
        count -= 1 # If n is a perfect square, remove one extra count
    return count
```